# Efficient handling of mouse clicks

Tags: java, algorithm, event-handling, listener, mouse

I'm wondering if there's an efficient way of handling mouse clicks within a range of coordinates rather than with a bunch of if-statements.  This leads me into thinking about using a Listener to handle it, however is it even possible to assign a Listener to an arbitrary object?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about listening for mouse actions on a JComponent just as a JButton, you can add MouseListener to the JComponent.

If you are talking about objects created by you with which appeared as an image in the panel, you can add MouseListener to the panel which contains your object(s). On every mouse click, iterate through the objects in your panel and check whether the object contains your mouse cursor.

```
class DisplayPanel extends JPanel{

    //Your constructor and other members..
    public DisplayPanel(){
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e){
                for(MyObjects : obj)
                    if(obj.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
                        clickedObj = obj;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> Do you mean have the arbitrary class extend JComponent? What if it already extends another class?

An alternative would be considering making a customized JComponent. However if your object already extends to another class. You may consider composition over inheritance:

```
class ArbritaryComponent extends JComponent{
    private ArbritaryObject obj;
}

class ArbritaryObject extends SomeClass{
    private Image image;
}
```

Then add the listener to your customized component.
To get a brief idea of customizing JComponent: [Extending JComponent](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ExtendsJComponenttocreatedrawingpad.htm)

Comment: I'm trying to steer clear of iteration if possible, but yes it's for an image that appears on a JFrame, but is an object created by me.

Comment: Not enough that, when iterating over them, would slow down the program, but I'm curious if there's another way handling it.

Comment: An alternative is to make a customized JComponent. Since JComponent allows ActionListener to be added to it, in that case you don't have to iterate it.

Comment: Do you mean have the arbitrary class extend JComponent?  What if it already extends another class?

Comment: Yes, by extending JComponent. If your object already extends another class, then you have to tweak on your design. An approach would be using composition over inheritance. That is, create a new class which extends JComponent and let that class contains your arbitrary object as one of its members.